# Python efficient sort of parallel lists in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

Title pretty much says it all, I'm looking to efficiently sort a dictionary of parallel lists.

```
unsorted_my_dict = {
   'key_one': [1,6,2,3],
   'key_two': [4,1,9,7],
   'key_three': [1,2,4,3],
   ...
}
sorted_my_dict = {
   'key_one': [1,6,3,2],
   'key_two': [4,1,7,9],
   'key_three': [1,2,3,4],
   ...
}
```

I want to sort `key_three`, and all the other lists in that dictionary in parallel. There are a few similar questions but I'm struggling because I have an unknown number of keys in the dictionary to be sorted, and I only know the name of the key I want to sort on (`key_three`).

Looking to to do this with vanilla Python, no 3rd party dependencies.

Edit 1: 
What do I mean by in parallel? I mean that if I sort `key_three`, which requires swapping the last two values, that all other lists in the dictionary will have their last two values swapped as well.

Edit 2: Python 3.4 specifically

Comment: So you want to get a copy of the dict with a value sorted? Or sort the list in the original dict?

Comment: what do you mean by "in parallel"? And in what sense is `[1,6,3,2]` sorted? Or `[4,1,7,9]`? What's the rule?

Comment: In parellel meaning that if I swap values at index 2 and 3 in key_three and call it sorted, that the other lists experience swaps at the same index.

Comment: @LBaelish please add this to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first sort an `enumerate` of the target list to recover the desired order of indices and then rearrange each list in that order.

```
my_dict = {
   'key_one': [1,6,2,3],
   'key_two': [4,1,9,7],
   'key_three': [1,2,4,3],
}


def parallel_sort(d, key):
    index_order = [i for i, _ in sorted(enumerate(d[key]), key=lambda x: x[1])]
    return {k: [v[i] for i in index_order] for k, v in d.items()}

print(parallel_sort(my_dict, 'key_three'))
```

### Output

```
{'key_one': [1, 6, 3, 2],
 'key_two': [4, 1, 7, 9],
 'key_three': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: maybe just `index_order = [i for _, i in zip(d[key], range(len(d[key]))]`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It would work, but it seems like a lot of work just no to use a key

Comment: Yeah, I guess I error on the side of not using g a key function if possible

Answer (score 1):

`zip` the keys together, sort on a key function based on the relevant item, , then `zip` again to restore the original form:

```
sorted_value_groups = sorted(zip(*unsorted_my_dict.values()), key=lambda _, it=iter(unsorted_my_dict['key_three']): next(it))
sorted_values = zip(*sorted_value_groups)
sorted_my_dict = {k: list(newvals) for k, newvals in zip(unsorted_my_dict, sorted_values)}
```

Not at all clean, I mostly just posted this for funsies. One-liner is:

```
sorted_my_dict = {k: list(newvals) for k, newvals in zip(unsorted_my_dict, zip(*sorted(zip(*unsorted_my_dict.values()), key=lambda _, it=iter(unsorted_my_dict['key_three']): next(it))))}
```

This works because, while `dict` iteration order isn't guaranteed prior to 3.7, the order is guaranteed to be repeatable for an unmodified `dict`. Similarly, the `key` function is executed in order from start to finish, so pulling the key by repeated iteration is safe. We just detach all the values, group them by index, sort the groups by the index key, regroup them by key, and reattach them to their original keys.

Output is exactly as requested (and the order of the original keys is preserved on CPython 3.6 or any Python 3.7 or higher):

```
sorted_my_dict = {
   'key_one': [1,6,3,2],
   'key_two': [4,1,7,9],
   'key_three': [1,2,3,4]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First with the given key on which sorting is done, you can get the indices order. You that sequence to rearrange the remaining lists in the dictionary.

```
unsorted_my_dict = {
'key_one': [1, 6, 2, 3],
'key_two': [4, 1, 9, 7],
'key_three': [1, 2, 4, 3],
}


def sort_parallel_by_key(my_dict, key):
    def sort_by_indices(idx_seq):
        return {k: [v[i] for i in idx_seq] for k, v in my_dict.items()}

    indexes = [idx for idx, _ in sorted(enumerate(my_dict[key]), key=lambda foo: foo[1])]
    return sort_by_indices(indexes)


print(sort_parallel_by_key(unsorted_my_dict, 'key_three'))
```